# Чтение данных, после отправки ajax запроса, методом POST

Tags: php, ajax

Делаю отправку запроса

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","./?idQ="+idQuestion+"&t="+token+"&idU="+idUser,true);
```

Как потом прочитать эти данные?

Если потом выводить вот так

```
echo $_GET['idQ'];
```

то ничего не выводит.
Выводит, если только выводить вот так

```
echo $_POST['idQ']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POST` запрос выводят так:

```
echo $_POST['idQ'];
```

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно что-то такое?

```ajax
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var body = 'idQ=' + encodeURIComponent(idQuestion) +
  '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(token) + 'idU=' + encodeURIComponent(idUser) ;

xmlhttp.open("POST", './', true)
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

xmlhttp.send(body);
```

Comment: не выводится так

Comment: Вообще, насколько я знаю, эта функция отправляет GET запросы.

Comment: А как отправить POST запрос?

Comment: В методе POST параметры передаются не в URL, а в теле запроса.

Comment: так? xmlhttp.send("idQ=idQuestion&token=idU");

Comment: Добавил в ответ